# Return/Redirect to the same page after Twitter Authorisation?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a question about `Redirecting Users from Twitter API to the same original page` but I think using an example will make it more clear.

> Example: http://twitition.com/6v9yf

**When you click on the sign button it will direct you to authorise your Twitter account, then it will validate and stuff then it will take you back to the same page you were in it. 
How exactly this is done? After twitter authorise your account, it will redirect you to the callback page then in the callback page does it stuff.**

**So, how can I can tell the callback page to redirect to the same page before?**

*I thought of using session keys to detect which page I was in before, I think it's not ideal though.*

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

More about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

This will redirect you to the last visited page when you logged in.